# SQL select by column of newest element of has_many relationship

Tags: mysql, sqlite, foreign-key-relationship

In my project I have a `tasks`*(id, name)* table. I also have a `status_updates`*(id, task_id, user_id, status, created_at)* table.

**I want to select tasks whose newest status_update equals a certain status.**

I cannot figure out how to combine the following things, however:

1. Only use the newest status_update for each task.
2. Filter away the status_updates that do not have the correct status.
3. Wrap this in a INNER JOIN so the final result is a collection of tasks.

When using GROUP_BY, it seems that 1. and 2. cancel each other out. An example:

```
SELECT * FROM status_updates GROUP BY task_id ORDER created_at DESC
```

gives back only the newest status_update for each task.
However, this:

```
SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE status='1' GROUP BY task_id ORDER created_at DESC
```

executes the WHERE before the ORDER, thus giving back *from the ones with a correct status, the newest*, instead of *from the newest, only those with a correct status*.

I also tried using HAVING, but as it only works on aggregate columns I could not figure out how to use it properly, or if it was at all helpful in this scenario.

I am using Ruby on Rails, so I'd like an answer to work both on MySQL as well as SQLite.

Comment: These queries would result in a syntax error, so your question is unclear

Comment: You are wrong about the first query. It doesn't give you back the newest status_update for each task - or if it does, it is sheer luck. This query actually gives you one line per task each with one of its records arbitrarily chosen. Afterwards it orders the tasks by the dates found in these rather randdomly chosen records. (Well, to be precise: it is even not guaranteed that you get complete records. You *could* for example get the date from one record and the status from another, but that's highly unlikely.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for that clarification. What a strange behaviour, that it returns an arbitrary record, and that it might split records. Is the arbitrary record chosen on however the data happens to be structured currently inside the DB?

Comment: It is not that strange. It's just that you limit your results to one row per `task_id` and naturally you should tell the DBMS which values to pick for such a row, e.g. the `MAX(status)` or the `MIN(created_at)`. But you don't. So the `status` in the resulting row can be `MIN(status)` or `MAX(status)` or any other, probably the one the DBMS finds first (which depends on how the rows are stored in the database and how the DBMS accesses them). This is true for all values...

Comment: ... So the DBMS *could* even pick the `status` from one record and `created_at` from another. (This is not very likely, as that would probably be unnecessary extra work, but well, maybe the DBMS doesn't access the table itself, but chooses to collect the data from different indexes, then it really could get the values from different table records.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    T.id,
    T.name,
    SU.status
FROM
    Tasks T
INNER JOIN (SELECT task_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at FROM Status_Updates GROUP BY task_id) SQ ON SQ.task_id = T.id
INNER JOIN Status_Updates SU ON
    SU.task_id = SQ.task_id AND
    SU.created_at = SQ.max_created_at
WHERE
    SU.status = '1'
```

Using window functions and a CTE (although not currently supported by your RDBMS, they are by many and could be in the future). This one has the advantage that it handles ties better:

```
WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        T.id,
        T.name,
        SU.status,
        ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY T.id ORDER BY SU.created_at DESC, id DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        Tasks T
    INNER JOIN Status_Updates SU ON SU.task_id = T.id
)
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    status
FROM
    MyCTE
WHERE
    row_num = 1
```

Comment: I am surprised to read that you think the latest versions of MySQL and SQLite to support windowing functions. I don't see anything in their docs hinting at this. Where did you get this from?

Comment: Just went back to the blog that mentioned it and it looks like I did misread it. SQL Lite recently implemented recursive CTEs, but the author was **asking** for window functions with examples of how they would be written, not how they currently can be written. I'll adjust my answer.